# Cant build php7.0-fpm dockerfile The repository Release file

Tags: docker, php-fpm, docker-compose

docker build -t php7-fpm-custom .
build on ubuntu 22.04 minimal

```
Reading package lists...
```

W: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

**Dockerfile** from here https://github.com/wpengine/php-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile.php7.0

```
FROM php:7.0-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && \
   apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
   git \
   libmemcached-dev \
   libz-dev \
   libpq-dev \
   libjpeg-dev \
   libfreetype6-dev \
   libssl-dev \
   libmcrypt-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install mcrypt
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_mysql

# install the PHP gd library
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd \
   --enable-gd-native-ttf \
   --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib \
   --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/freetype2 && \
   docker-php-ext-install gd

# install the soap extension
RUN apt-get update -yqq && \
   apt-get -y install libxml2-dev && \
   docker-php-ext-install soap

# install Php Redis Extension
RUN pecl install -o -f redis \
   &&  rm -rf /tmp/pear \
   &&  docker-php-ext-enable redis

# install the mongodb extension
RUN pecl install mongodb && docker-php-ext-enable mongodb

# install bcmath, mbstring and zip extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath && \
   docker-php-ext-install mbstring && \
   docker-php-ext-install zip

# enable Exif PHP extentions requirements
RUN docker-php-ext-install exif

# tokenizer Modifications:
RUN docker-php-ext-install tokenizer

# install intl and requirements
RUN apt-get update -yqq && \
   apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev libicu-dev g++ && \
   docker-php-ext-configure intl && \
   docker-php-ext-install intl

# install the ghostscript extension for PDF editing
RUN apt-get update -yqq \
   && apt-get install -y \
   poppler-utils \
   ghostscript

# LDAP:
RUN apt-get update -yqq && \
   apt-get install -y libldap2-dev && \
   docker-php-ext-configure ldap --with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ && \
   docker-php-ext-install ldap

RUN yes "" | pecl install msgpack-beta \
   && echo "extension=msgpack.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ext-msgpack.ini

# compile igbinary extension
RUN cd /tmp/ && git clone https://github.com/igbinary/igbinary "php-igbinary" && \
   cd php-igbinary && \
   phpize && \
   ./configure && \
   make && \
   make install && \
   make clean && \
   docker-php-ext-enable igbinary

# curl extension
RUN apt-get install -y curl libcurl4-openssl-dev --no-install-recommends && \
   docker-php-ext-install curl

# data structures extension
RUN pecl install ds && \
   docker-php-ext-enable ds

# imagick
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmagickwand-6.q16-dev --no-install-recommends && \
   ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin-Q16/MagickWand-config /usr/bin && \
   pecl install imagick && \
   echo "extension=imagick.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ext-imagick.ini

# ssh2 module
RUN apt-get install -y libssh2-1-dev && \
   pecl install ssh2-1.0 && \
   docker-php-ext-enable ssh2

# php-module: curl dom bz2 gd json mysqli pcntl pdo pdo_mysql phar posix
RUN apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libbz2-dev re2c libpng++-dev \
   libjpeg-dev libvpx-dev zlib1g-dev libgd-dev \
   libtidy-dev libxslt1-dev libmagic-dev libexif-dev file \
   sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev libxslt-dev

RUN export CFLAGS="-I/usr/src/php" && \
   docker-php-ext-install xmlreader xmlwriter

RUN docker-php-ext-configure json && \
   docker-php-ext-configure session && \
   docker-php-ext-configure ctype && \
   docker-php-ext-configure tokenizer && \
   docker-php-ext-configure simplexml && \
   docker-php-ext-configure dom && \
   docker-php-ext-configure mbstring && \
   docker-php-ext-configure zip && \
   docker-php-ext-configure pdo && \
   docker-php-ext-configure pdo_sqlite && \
   docker-php-ext-configure pdo_mysql && \
   docker-php-ext-configure mysqli && \
   docker-php-ext-configure iconv && \
   docker-php-ext-configure xml && \
   docker-php-ext-configure phar

RUN docker-php-ext-install \
   dom \
   bz2 \
   json \
   pcntl \
   phar \
   posix \
   simplexml \
   soap \
   tidy \
   xml \
   xmlrpc \
   xsl \
   calendar \
   ctype \
   fileinfo \
   ftp \
   sysvmsg \
   sysvsem \
   sysvshm

# install the php memcache & memcached extension
RUN set -x \
   && apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends unzip libssl-dev libpcre3 libpcre3-dev \
   && cd /tmp \
   && curl -sSL -o php7.zip https://github.com/websupport-sk/pecl-memcache/archive/php7.zip \
   && unzip php7 \
   && cd pecl-memcache-php7 \
   && /usr/local/bin/phpize \
   && ./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config \
   && make \
   && make install \
   && echo "extension=memcache.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ext-memcache.ini \
   && rm -rf /tmp/pecl-memcache-php7 php7.zip

RUN curl -L -o /tmp/memcached.tar.gz "https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/archive/php7.tar.gz" \
   && mkdir -p memcached \
   && tar -C memcached -zxvf /tmp/memcached.tar.gz --strip 1 \
   && ( \
   cd memcached \
   && phpize \
   && ./configure \
   && make -j$(nproc) \
   && make install \
   ) \
   && rm -r memcached \
   && rm /tmp/memcached.tar.gz \
   && docker-php-ext-enable memcached

# mhash
RUN apt-get install -y libmhash2 libmhash-dev libc-client-dev libkrb5-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl \
   && docker-php-ext-install imap

RUN docker-php-ext-configure hash --with-mhash && \
   docker-php-ext-install hash

# Opcache
RUN docker-php-ext-install opcache

# install APCu
RUN pecl install apcu-5.1.8 && \
   pecl install apcu_bc-1.0.3 && \
   docker-php-ext-enable apcu --ini-name 10-docker-php-ext-apcu.ini && \
   docker-php-ext-enable apc --ini-name 20-docker-php-ext-apc.ini

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y gnupg apt-transport-https locales

# install MSSQL support
# install ODBC driver
#RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - && \
#    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/8/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list && \
#    export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && apt-get update -y && \
#    ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql unixodbc-dev
#RUN set -xe \
#    && pecl install pdo_sqlsrv \
#    && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_sqlsrv \
#    && apt-get purge -y unixodbc-dev && apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get clean

# set locale to utf-8
RUN echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen && \
   locale-gen
ENV LANG='en_US.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='en_US:en' LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Final Touches
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

# install required libs for health check
RUN apt-get -y install libfcgi0ldbl nano htop iotop lsof cron mariadb-client redis-tools

# install NewRelic agent
RUN echo 'deb http://apt.newrelic.com/debian/ newrelic non-free' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/newrelic.list && \
   curl https://download.newrelic.com/548C16BF.gpg | apt-key add - && \
   apt-get -y update && \
   DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install newrelic-php5 newrelic-sysmond && \
   export NR_INSTALL_SILENT=1 && newrelic-install install

# install SendGrid
RUN echo "postfix postfix/mailname string localhost" | debconf-set-selections && \
   echo "postfix postfix/main_mailer_type string 'Internet Site'" | debconf-set-selections && \
   DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install postfix libsasl2-modules -y

# Set default work directory
ADD scripts/* /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x  /usr/local/bin/*

# Health check
RUN echo '#!/bin/bash' > /healthcheck && \
   echo 'SCRIPT_NAME=/health SCRIPT_FILENAME=/health REQUEST_METHOD=GET cgi-fcgi -bind -connect 127.0.0.1:9000 || exit 1' >> /healthcheck && \
   chmod +x /healthcheck

# Clean up
RUN apt-get remove -y git && apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

WORKDIR /
```

**source  archive i think here https://wiki.debian.org/DebianStretch**

Comment: Both Debian Stretch and PHP 7.0 have reached the end-of-life and are unsupported, so the question is off-topic here.